# Error installing SQL Server 2016 Code 0X800736CC

Tags: sql-server

I've reformatted my machine around 3 times. I'm on windows 10 and I've selected the erase all apps and files option and I'm still not able to install sql server express 2016. I'm presented with this error when trying to install.
  `‘Microsoft.VC80.MFC,version=”8.0.50727.4053″,publicKeyToken=”1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b”,processorArchitecture=”x86″,type=”win32″‘. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x800736CC.`

I've tried many many things. I've reformatted, I've tried running the file as admin, tried other versions such as stand edition 2012, tried to install the files while deleting 2010 c++ distribution. I've ran .net repair tool and nothing as well.

The problem stemmed when I manually uninstalled .net 4.5.1 framework using add/remove programs. I think my system files or registry is corrupted.

Comment: see may be helpfull http://shawndowler.com/blog/2012/06/25/microsoft-sql-server-installation-issue-fix/

Answer (score 0):

I think the error says, you have a 32 bit machine(processorArchitecture=”x86″) and you are trying to install 64 bit app ,which is not possible

further [there is no 32 bit version of SQLSERVER from SQL2016 onwards](http://sqlha.com/2015/10/05/32-bit-server-based-sql-server-is-finally-dead/)

> Some of you may have noticed that Microsoft recently released SQL Server 2016 CTP 2.4. There is one major change that I am very happy about – x86, or the 32-bit version, is no longer included. SQL Server 2016 is now 64-bit only

you can try downloading SQL2014 express version which comes in both versions..here is a link to download :[Download SQL Server Express](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx)